# serialize the data of a form and deserialize it into an associative array

Tags: javascript, php

when I use `$('#myForm').serialize()` to post all fields of a form ( It contains only many groups of radio buttons), I get a POST data like this:

```
radio1=blue&radio2=red&radio3=white
```

But i don t know how to decode (unserialize) it in PHP to get an associative array like this:

```
$myArray = array("radio1"=>"blue", "radio2"=>"red", "radio3"=>"white");
```

**EDIT:** Here is the html code:

```
for( $i=1; $i<=$unknownNumber; $i++ ){

   echo("<input type=\"radio\" name=\""."radio".$i."\" value=\"blue\" checked>");
   echo("<input type=\"radio\" name=\""."radio".$i."\" value=\"red\">");
   echo("<input type=\"radio\" name=\""."radio".$i."\" value=\"white\">");
}
```

And below is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name^="radio"]').on('click', function() {
        $.post( "process.php", $("#myForm").serialize(), function(data){
            alert('Good');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sounds unlikely. Can you post your exact jQuery and php code?

Comment: @jeroen i have edited the question and add the jQuery code.

Comment: @stfsnguec look at my answer, $_POST will return array with your data
`$array = $_POST;`
`$radio1 = $array['radio1'] or $_POST['radio1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parse_str` function in php:

```
 $arr = array();
 parse_str('radio1=blue&radio2=red&radio3=white',$arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

[PHP parse_str Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (unserialize) in php
use `$_POST['radio1'] (It contains the value 'blue')`

`$_POST  type array()` contains all the post data that was send by Ajax or from submit

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_str('radio1=blue&radio2=red&radio3=white',$postdata);

var_dump($postdata);
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) {
  ["radio1"]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  ["radio2"]=>
  string(3) "red"
  ["radio3"]=>
  string(5) "white"
}
```